# Why is $\ln2\approx 0.4^{0.4}$?

Tags: logarithms, power-series, real-numbers, transcendental-functions

Just stumbled upon
$$\ln2\approx 0.4^{0.4}$$
and wondered if that's just a coincidence, or whether there's some deeper reason?

$$\ln2 - 0.4^{0.4}\approx 0.00000234$$
which is a relative error of just $3.37\cdot10^{-6}$, which is remarkable (better than 17 bits / better than 5 decimals). It's
$$
0.4^{0.4} = \sqrt[5]{4/25}
$$
but I still do not see a connection. The values are:
$$\begin{align}
\ln2      &\approx 0.69314718 \\
0.4^{0.4} &\approx 0.69314484
\end{align}$$

Comment: I checked some representations from [Wikipedia on $\ln 2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm_of_2#Series_representations), but nothing seems to be related (like iterating 5-roots or so).

Comment: Really close ! One solution of $x^x=\ln(2)$ is $$0.4000402600816899099383062722546666\cdots$$

Comment: The solution to $x^x=\ln(2)$ is $e^{W(\ln(\ln(2))}$ and $\ln(\ln(2))\approx -\frac1e$. The Product logarithm has [this expansion at $x=-\frac1e$](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/06/01/02/0001/), so $x^x=\ln(2)\implies x\approx e^{-1+\sqrt{2e}\sqrt{\ln(\ln(2))+\frac1e}}\approx0.400994,x\approx e^{-1}$. Maybe given $x\approx e^{-1}$, $\ln(2)\approx (e^{-1})^{e^{-1}}\approx 0.6922$ and $\frac1e\approx 0.4$, so $\ln(2)\approx 0.4^{0.4}$ which is more accurate. However, it is still not clear how all of these ideas link together.

Comment: @Peter: The question is then if 0.4 is the 1st term of some (rapidly converging) expansion for $\ln 2$.

Comment: @Peter: Now find one with a relative error a 100 times lower.

Comment: That the difference is so small does not mean that the root is also so close at $0.4$